# How to filter STUN packets by Message Transaction ID in wireshark

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, stun

I am using Wireshark Network Protocol Analyzer 1.12.2 (Os: Windows). Is it possible to filter stun packets by Message Transaction ID from tcpdump using this software? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter on stun.id as in the picture below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFGs.png:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Now I can easily filter stun packets by this way.... thanks again :)